# Fragment duplicates when I clean the cache

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm new here, my english is a little bit bad but I'll try.

In Android I have a `Fragment` inside an `Activity` with a `TextView` and a `RecyclerView`.
When the `Activity` opens the `Fragment` is attached to it, but when I get out of the app and delete the cache and open the app again the `Fragment` duplicate itself.

[Whithout cleaning cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHzh2.jpg)

[After cache is cleaned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyaa8.jpg)

My Activity:

```java
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeView {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    int index;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    //Fragments
    MyPetsFragment myPetsFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        index = 0;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.IdToolbar);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.IdDrawerLayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.IdNavigationView);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_menu);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LinearLayout NavigationViewMyPets = findViewById(R.id.IdNavigationViewMyPets);
        LinearLayout NavigationViewVetsNearYou = findViewById(R.id.IdNavigationViewVetsNearYou);
        LinearLayout NavigationViewEnergy = findViewById(R.id.IdNavigationViewEnergy);
        LinearLayout NavigationViewPetMatch = findViewById(R.id.IdNavigationViewPetMatch);

        myPetsFragment = new MyPetsFragment();

        if (!myPetsFragment.isAdded()){
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.IdFragmentContainer, myPetsFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }


        NavigationViewMyPets.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           openFragmentWithoutArguments(myPetsFragment,fragmentTransaction,fragmentManager);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        });
        NavigationViewVetsNearYou.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.v("Mensaje", "Near");
        });
        NavigationViewEnergy.setOnClickListener(v -> {});
        NavigationViewPetMatch.setOnClickListener(v -> {});

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mytopmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

            case R.id.IdMenuItemContactUs:
                return true;

            case R.id.IdMenuItemProfile:
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void openFragmentWithoutArguments(Fragment fragment, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.IdFragmentContainer, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

My Fragment´s XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.fragment.MyPetsFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/IdScrollViewMyPetsFragment"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Pets"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/IdRecyclerViewMyPets"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/IdButtonAddPet"
        style="@style/Button_Rounded_Blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Add Pet"
        android:textAllCaps="false"></Button>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What's the overridden method '`openFragmentWithoutArguments`' and what does it override?

Comment: @LucaMurra its call when one of the menu item in the navigationview is tapped, and opens a fragment deppending on the menu item that's tapped

Comment: But why there's the `@Override` annotation?

Comment: @LucaMurra because its implemented from the interface "HomeView" that I created

Comment: Please, consider using the standard local-variable notation: as you can see, the word `NavigationViewMyPets` and similar are wrong-interpreted by Stack Overflow color-formatter, this because the first letter is capital, when it should be tiny

Comment: Ok, that of the interface is what I was looking for; consider adding the definition of the class (with `extends` and `implements` keywords) in your post

Comment: @LucaMurra Oh okey, im new here, thanks for the advise

Comment: @JoMomma Sure!!